# Sinatra Haml: Access object attributes

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I´m new to sinatra and haml. I am writing a simple todo application. 
In the controller I am creating a list of todo-Objects. Every todo has for example the attributes "title" and "priority". The list of todos is an attribute of the sinatra controller (@todos = .. list of todo objects)

I can access/iterate the list of todos with

```
%ul
     - @todos.each do |todo|
          %li= todo ....
```

and so on.

**But how can I access the attributes of my todo-objects ("title", "priority") ?**
What is the syntax for that?
Tried several but didn´t find the right one..

Can you help me?

Comment: This has less to do with Sinatra and more to do with how you've built out the rest of your application. Are you using ActiveRecord in conjunction with Sinatra? A bit more information is needed to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use datamapper (activerecord doesn't differ):

in controller:

```
get '/' do
  @todos = Todo.all
  haml :todo
end
```

in view:

```
%ul
  -@todos.each do |todo|
    %li
      =todo.title
      %br
      =todo.task
```

All things is objects and no difference where you can access to it properties.
You can do:

```
 ...
 -Todo.all.each do |todo|
 ...
```

but this not good way.

Comment: dude, jibasig, if it works, you really should give Zuzuka credit.